# Finding the common eigenvectors of two matrices

Tags: eigenvalue, eigenvector

I want to find the common eigenvectors of two symmetric matrices with the same dimension in R
Assuming two matrices L1 and L2 I am looking for vector X such that
L1*X = (landa)L2*X
where landa is the eigen value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term you are looking for is [Generalized Eigenvalue Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigendecomposition_of_a_matrix#Generalized_eigenvalue_problem). This is a well researched linear algebra problem.

In terms of implementation, I suggest looking at a special [Netlib section](https://www.netlib.org/lapack/lug/node33.html), where I think your matrices will satisfy [Generalized Symmetric Definite Eigenproblems solver](https://www.netlib.org/lapack/lug/node34.html) requirements.

[Intel MKL](https://software.intel.com/en-us/mkl-developer-reference-c-generalized-symmetric-definite-eigenvalue-problems-lapack-computational-routines) provides the functionality directly available from C, Fortran, and, as far as I know, Python.